# Moment.js : does en locale should display time in 12 hours format?

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

I`m using Moment.js 2.10.3.
In according to moment-with-locales.js :

```
var defaultLongDateFormat = {
    LTS  : 'h:mm:ss A',
    LT   : 'h:mm A',
    L    : 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    LL   : 'MMMM D, YYYY',
    LLL  : 'MMMM D, YYYY LT',
    LLLL : 'dddd, MMMM D, YYYY LT'
};
```

Does it mean en locale should display time in 12 hours format with LTS format ?

[a jsfiddle demonstrating the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ezoqkgca/4/)

Sorry, my English is not very good now...

```js
var locale = "en";
var timeOffset = 540;

var currentTimeOffset = moment().utcOffset(timeOffset).locale(locale).format("LTS");
document.getElementById("timeOffset").innerHTML = currentTimeOffset;

var elLocale = moment.utc(currentTimeOffset, "LTS", 'el');

document.getElementById("elLocaleHours").innerHTML = elLocale.hours();
document.getElementById("elLocaleMinutes").innerHTML = elLocale.minutes();
document.getElementById("elLocaleSeconds").innerHTML = elLocale.seconds(); 


var enLocale = moment.utc(currentTimeOffset, "LTS", locale); 

document.getElementById("enLocaleHours").innerHTML = enLocale.hours();
document.getElementById("enLocaleMinutes").innerHTML = enLocale.minutes();
document.getElementById("enLocaleSeconds").innerHTML = enLocale.seconds(); 

var beLocale = moment.utc(currentTimeOffset, "LTS", 'be'); 

document.getElementById("beLocaleHours").innerHTML = beLocale.hours();
document.getElementById("beLocaleMinutes").innerHTML = beLocale.minutes();
document.getElementById("beLocaleSeconds").innerHTML = beLocale.seconds();
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<div id="timeOffset"></div>
<div id="elLocale"> elLocale (should be 12 h format) :
    <span id="elLocaleHours"></span>&nbsp; : &nbsp;
    <span id="elLocaleMinutes"></span>&nbsp; : &nbsp;
    <span id="elLocaleSeconds"></span>
</div>
<div id="enLocale"> enLocale (should be 12 h format) :
    <span id="enLocaleHours"></span>&nbsp; : &nbsp;
    <span id="enLocaleMinutes"></span>&nbsp; : &nbsp;
    <span id="enLocaleSeconds"></span>
</div>

<div id="beLocale"> beLocale (should be 24 h format) :
    <span id="beLocaleHours"></span>&nbsp; : &nbsp;
    <span id="beLocaleMinutes"></span>&nbsp; : &nbsp;
    <span id="beLocaleSeconds"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs I would expect `enLocale.hours()` to always return the hours in the `0 - 23` range:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/

> As with the other getters for durations, moment.duration().hours()
>   gets the hours (0 - 23).

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/hour/

> Accepts numbers from 0 to 23. If the range is exceeded, it will bubble
>   up to the day.

You might instead want to display it using [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), which is based on a specific locale:

> Because preferred formatting differs based on locale, there are a few
>   tokens that can be used to format a moment based on its locale.

Comment: But i need a Date object to get hours/minutes/seconds with standard methods. Parse string is not a good idea because of different locales . And in my example we can see different time format with locales.

Comment: @Sergey: Sorry, what is your issue then? `enLocale` seems to be exactly the date object with standard methods. And if you want to ouput the date as a localized string, you would use a formatter. Can you please try to explain your problem again?

Comment: In my example some of locales use 12h format and other use 24 format:
`code`
    2:56:01 PM
    elLocale (should be 12 h format) : 2  :   56  :   1
    enLocale (should be 12 h format) : 14  :   56  :   1
    beLocale (should be 24 h format) : 2  :   56  :   1
`code`

Comment: Is it a bug or feature ?